# VS17 professional 15.7.5 doesn't show variables while debugging on hover in ashx files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, ashx

VS17 professional 15.7.5 doesn't show variables while debugging on hover in ashx files. I have exact the same project and the same code running in VS15 enterprise and in VS15 I can see variables on hover in ashx file. any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VS17 professional 15.7.5 doesn't show variables while debugging on hover in ashx files

Yes, this is a known issue on the previous version Visual Studio. You can find this issue has been reported on Developer Community [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/291011/vs2017-1575-community-debugger-not-showing-variabl.html) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246728/vs2017-1570-community-debugger-not-showing-variabl.html).

And this issue is fixed at version 15.8.0, now the latest version of Visual Studio is 15.8.8, you can update your Visual Studio to the latest version to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps.